# How to add ComboBox.SelectedIndex as FK

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, entity-framework-4.1, foreign-keys

I am having a form which contains a ComboBox which contains the data about cities.
I want to insert FK cityid into my Employee table. So how can i add?

I am doing the following things but it will gives me an error:

```
Payroll.Entities.City p = (Payroll.Entities.City) cmbCity.SelectedIndex;
```

how can I assign city id in employee table?

Comment: What is the definition of `City`? Is it a class? How can you cast class onto integer?

Comment: cant convert int to entity.payroll.city

Answer (score 1):

```
var city = db.Cities.Single(c => c.Id == Int32.Parse(cmbCity.SelectedValue));
employee.City = city;
```

Comment: i cant access Cities like this in Entity framework.. it is possible in LINQ

Comment: How do you get Employees? Why can't you access Cities?

Comment: @abatishchev SelectedIndex can not be the Id, Its just an index!

Answer (score 1):

If you load the Cities into the combo box, then `SelectedItem` should work:

```
Payroll.Entities.City p = (Payroll.Entities.City) cmbCity.SelectedItem;
```

But if you are only loading partial city data into the combo box, Then something like this should work:

```
var p = db.Cities.Single(c => c.Name == cmbCity.SelectedValue);
//or
//var p = db.Cities.Single(c => c.Name == cmbCity.Text);
```

Answer (score -1):

ssuming EntityObj is your Entity Object.

```
Payroll.Entities.Employee objEmp = new Payroll.Entities.Employee();
objEmp.cityid = int.Parse(cmbCity.SelectedValue);
EntityObj.AddToEmployee(objEmp);
EntityObj.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: **objEmp.cityid = cmbCity.SelectedValue;** gives me error like cant convert implicit type string to entity.payroll.city